# Exchange setup created many nuisance domain accounts

Tags: exchange, installation

New at this, so may be asking the wrong questions. Please advise accordingly.

I've just finished installing Exchange 2013 into my small Server Essentials 2012 R2 domain (I put it on a separate VM from the DC). I worked on it all day yesterday.

Much to my chagrin, I received a Health Report warning this morning that I'd exceeded my 25-account allotment in WSE. Needless to say, this surprised me—I'd only created 10 so far. There should've been plenty of room.

Well, it seems that Exchange Setup had gone and added its own—18 of them, to be exact. Here's what I've got:

[image: Nuisance accounts]

Do I really need all of these? What are they used for? How quickly would Exchange go belly-up if I just deleted them all?

I have to do something... I don't know whether the DC's going to shut me down over this, but I'd hate to consider it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [Exchange 2013 Monitoring Mailboxes](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2015/03/20/exchange-2013-monitoring-mailboxes.aspx) which were added to support Managed Availability. It basically performs various actions to simulate users and confirm the mail server is functioning well.

There is a service that can be turned off so this monitoring stops. You can then disable / delete the accounts. There are also some scheduled tasks that do a lot of performance logging which probably isn't needed on such a small server, these can be disabled as well.

Service:

1. Exchange Health Manager Service

Scheduler Tasks

1. \Microsoft\Windows\PLA\ExchangeDiagnosticsDailyPerformanceLog
2. \Microsoft\Windows\PLA\ExchangeDiagnosticsPerformanceLog

Ref: http://ficility.net article [How to disable Managed Availability in Exchange 2013](http://ficility.net/2013/07/08/how-to-disable-managed-availability-in-exchange-2013/)

Comment: Excellent! We're almost home...  I was able to remove 9 of the 11 active accounts, via the WSE Dashboard. Oddly, these 11 didn't appear in the AD Users panel—only in the Dashboard. I received a very helpful 'unspecified error' when trying to remove SERVER3-001 and SERVER3-Mailbox-Database. Not sure how to proceed for those remaining 2. So—what of the inactive accounts not related to Managed Availability? Is it safe to remove those as well? FYI 6 of those other 7 DO exist in AD Users—the one beginning with $ doesn't.

Comment: Also strange... there's no MsExchSysObj node in AD, as shown in the TechNet blog. Users is the last sibling. Also I'm not able to remove ANY mailbox: `Get-Mailbox -Monitoring | ForEach-Object {Remove-Mailbox -Identity $_.Name -Permanent $true}` returns **Access Denied** and `Get-Mailbox -Monitoring | ForEach-Object {Remove-Mailbox -Identity $_.Name}` times out without any action.

Comment: OK, I've disabled (`Disable-Mailbox` instead of `Remove-Mailbox`) the `-Monitoring` and `-Arbitration` mailboxes and deleted their corresponding users from the Dashboard. All except `SystemMailbox{bb558c35-97f1-4cb9-8ff7-d53741dc928c}`, which is linked to my OAB. I suppose I'd better keep that one then. Any idea why the `-Monitoring` mailboxes weren't showing up in AD? If I could figure that out I'd be closer to figuring out why those two stragglers won't delete from the Dashboard (nothing in the event logs).

Comment: OK, got it. Satya weighed in with the answer over [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d35aa9f2-adc1-48da-a2a3-c7e9b77f3f6a/cant-remove-user-in-dashboard?forum=winserveressentials).